# Color only subsection header but NOT its toc entry

Tags: sectioning, color

I'm having hard times trying to color some lines of my document.

I want to color just the title of a subsection, but I don't want that the corresponding title in TOC is colored too.

What I have now is:

`\subsection{{\color{RoyalBlue}TITLE}}`

And this work for the subsection title, but it actually colors also the corresponding title in the TOC.

Thanks for helping,
Rosario

Comment: Please try `\subsection[TITLE]{{\color{RoyalBlue}TITLE}}`.

Comment: Thanks for answering Malipivo!

I just found the solution by doing this: 

`{\color{RoyalBlue}\subsection{TITLE}`

Works great ;)
Ciao!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way, if you don't need other changes to the typesetting of section titles, is with `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty,xcolor}
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section title}

\end{document}
```

[image]